# Creating a loud cracking sound to scare cats away forever and ever

Tags: arduino, amplifier, audio, sound

So we have some hardcore cats in our area, recording their glorious conquests with excrement. They don't scare easily. I'll be conducting psychological warfare, they must start associating some form of visual cue with being scared, and I'll have one real and maybe 6 fakes around the garden. Each day I'll move them a bit and switch out the real one. It will probably be a garden gnome or something equivalently horrific.

So I've picked out an arduino board, it will have standard 5v at 40 mA pins. I have a PIR sensor and some red LED's. I'd like to create a loud "crack" noise, like a gunshot or firework. Like an audio version of the flash or strobe. I've tried setting a piezo buzzer to go off when they are close but it just doesn't cut it. Neither does that very high pitched whiny anti-cat noise. In the worst case I will resort to some form of aggressive sprinkler system but that's suboptimal.

I was wondering if there is some sort of component which can make such a noise? Is there a simpler solution than going all out on speakers? I know what a capacitor is but I'm lost beyond, please aid our species against these fluffy faux-cute lawn-soiling horrors.

p.s. I do like cats but my father is allergic and they do relieve themselves all over our (now smelly) lawn a tad too often

Comment: I will admit that I laughed out loud at this title.

Comment: What about something like this or just going ultrasonic http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B0001A9TE2/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/190-6717918-1480116   I don't think my neighbors / police would take kindly to a gunshot sound cat deterrent :)

Comment: This seems to be a wider engineering problem, not really about a electrical component.  It doesn't seem appropriate for this site, but maybe over at the new Engineering.SE.

Comment: You could use a relay to control the power to a stun gun whose power button is locked in the active position. The, when you turn it on, you'll get a loud series of cracks. If you want to be more insane, you might be able to use it to ignite a primer from a bullet (NOTE: JUST THE PRIMER! As in: go to a store and buy a box of primers). Primers are loud and small. You SHOULD keep them a bit far away from the sensing zone because you shouldn't hit a primer too close to the cat (it's loud).

Comment: @Some Hardware Guy, One of the people in or neighbourhood has tried one of those but it doesn't seem to work at all. That and it can actually be heard by kids (and me). We have a lot of those and I assume the cats here have just gotten used to them, and or or are deaf.

Comment: @iAdjunct , that is by far the most insane and also efficient idea so far, kudos. I do feel bad for the cats though and only want to scar their psyche a little bit

Comment: I think you could make a nice loud banger using a solenoid gas valve, a tank of propane and a spark ignitor. Release the gas, timing it to allow it to mix with air in a semi-enclosed chamber, then ignite with a capacitive discharge into an ignition coil and spark plug. Making it safe and not annoying neighbors might be more of a challenge. Google bird banger cannons for more.

Comment: I'd be worried about what the cats are off plotting.....

Comment: Dog, big hawk, owl, water hose... if they are feral cats maybe  a BB gun.

Comment: Solenoid coil with an arm that bangs something, or just buy an alarm sounder. Glad I don't live next door to you... I'd vote sprinkler every time, it's quiet and they'll soon learn the loud noise can't hurt them.

Comment: Just thought: Many car/truck starter motors have a BIG solenoid with a heavy metal rod in the centre that engages the starter, that would bang a frying pan or something pretty loud. Just beware the load & back-emf of driving it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Making an alarm of some sort seems on-topic, although the question is written in such a way it could seem otherwise. :)

Comment: How bout get a dog?

Comment: Dog is no good, father is also allergic to those. I admit, buying a hunting hawk tickles my fancy, as does the solenoid, I'll go smaller for now though. Next try will be a sprinkler. Sprinkler is the next step yes. I've already tried cat politics as well, but now we have one cat which likes us and protects our garden, but it craps all over it itself. Let's hope this battle doesn't escalate too rapidly...

Comment: 5 years on :-). Not a crackling, but ... :-). Pressurise a PET softdrink bottle to 100 - 130 psi (700 kPa+). This can be done with a Schraeder vale in the cap or using dry ice. Arrange a solenoid activated needle that punctures the bottle 'on command". The tiniest hole will do :-). The gas pressure does the rest. This creates a seriously loud explosion. Seriously so. It's not overly dangerous [tm] but you wouldn't know it from the . Smaller ones can resist higher pressures. sound. Cats lose 3.14 lives per explosion if within 2 metres.  1.5l bottles are good.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want something like a **[buzzer](http://www.mouser.com/Electromechanical/Audio-Devices/Audio-Indicators-Alerts/_/N-awp3tZscv7?P=1z0x242Z1z0x245Z1z0x2wgZ1yzuikmZ1z0x2eeZ1yzp2ksZ1z0x24iZ1z0x2cjZ1z0x24cZ1z0x2aaZ1z0x1reZ1z0x2wiZ1z0x2dl&Keyword=buzzer&FS=True&Ns=Sound%20Pressure%20Level%7C1)**. Many times on electronics suppliers you can get very loud and easy to use pieces of equipment that are quite loud. For example, [this](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Mallory-Sonalert/MAS803Q/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsK322k1rNFfcuVkNjRFr8VeMEW1UZEwHQ%3D) device will generate 105dB. It might be loud enough for you, if not, you may need to look for louder ones, but it will be easy to use at 6V and 135mA requirement.

There are many ways to make a loud noise, but this is an easy one. Gong and other alarm bells can also be loud, but will be much more expensive and actually can be hard to find at this volume.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know they can go this high, that'll have to do for a first try. You also reminded me, maybe I can salvage one of those bell-hit things from an old alarm clock I have lying around. Let the warfare commence!

Comment: @ZirconCode - They get quite loud, and their dB/$ ratio is amazing. It is not a super-cap spark-gap, so it is lacking the WoW factor when you show your neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy a supercapacitor, put it through a relay, then put that to a small spark gap, you should be able to make a reasonably loud bang. I don't know if that's a very simple solution, or if it's in your budget.

Comment: I read up on it an it looks like fun. I might just try it later on ^^

Comment: proposed nickname for this device: *Katzenfaust*